# Why two numeric divide, the result is zero? using SQLDF in R

Tags: r, count, sqldf

I am using SQLDF in R. I count two different values from column 2 and column 3. I want to calculate column 2 / column 3, but the result is always zero.  Why?

Here is my code:

```
prouterInboundin4hours<-sqldf(

  " select `1st Segment Delivered Success Day`,   count (DISTINCT case  when 
  `Inbound Lead Time (hour)` < 4 then `First segment Order Number` END) 
  as 'Inbound< 4 hours Volume', 
  count (`First segment Order Number`) as 'Delivered Success Volume',
  count (DISTINCT case  when `Inbound Lead Time (hour)` < 4 then `First 
  segment Order Number` END) / count (`First segment Order Number`) 
  from prouter
   where Year ='Year2017'
  group by `1st Segment Delivered Success Day`
  "
   )
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in R, if you divide two integers you get another integer. Compare these two:

```
sqldf("select 1/2")
##    1/2
##  1   0

sqldf("select cast (1 as real)/2")
##   cast (1 as real)/2
## 1                0.5
```

Comment: One plus question, do you know how to turn 0.5 into 50.00%? thanks!

Comment: SQLite has the `printf` function.